# Wait between wget downloads

Tags: shell, ubuntu, command-line-interface, wget

I'm trying to download a directory (incl subs) from a website.
I'm using:

```
wget -r -e robots=off --no-parent --reject "index.html*" http://example.com/directory1/
```

Problem is, the server refuses connection after a bit, I think there's too many connections within a short amount of time. So what I'd like to do is insert a wait time (5 seconds) between each download/lookup. Is that possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `--wait`. From `wget(1)`:

```
   -w seconds
   --wait=seconds
       Wait the specified number of seconds between the retrievals.  Use
       of this option is recommended, as it lightens the server load by
       making the requests less frequent.  Instead of in seconds, the time
       can be specified in minutes using the "m" suffix, in hours using
       "h" suffix, or in days using "d" suffix.

       Specifying a large value for this option is useful if the network
       or the destination host is down, so that Wget can wait long enough
       to reasonably expect the network error to be fixed before the
       retry.  The waiting interval specified by this function is
       influenced by "--random-wait", which see.
```

I didn't know this either, but I found this answer in 15 seconds by using the `wget` manpage:

- Type `man wget`.
- You can use `/` to search, so I used `/wait`.
- It's the first hit!
- Press `q` to quit.